# JSch in Java -- How to confirm if SSH Connection or Tunnel is down?

Tags: java, jsch

I am writing an application in Java that talks to SSH Server and sends data via an SSH Tunnel.

Idea is to establish a tunnel on start-up and use that tunnel on individual requests such that a new connection is not created on each and every service request.

So, on startup, one piece of application establishes an SSH Connection and then creates Tunnel using session.setPortForwardingL().
On each request, other piece of application simply communicates with Local Port without even bothering about SSH Tunnel. It is job of the Tunnel to transport data written on local port (Tunnel source) to Tunnel destination.

With this approach there will be a need to keep the SSH Tunnel up and running all the time (whenever connection is possible).

I am struggling to find a Fail Proof Solution to keep the Tunnel alive.
- The method session.isConnected() does not return false even if the server connection is lost.
- Will sending keep alive message just before checking connection status set isConnected to false?
- Anyone implemented such a logic?

I am also open to any suggestions outside JSch as I am still in Design phase.

Comment: Lookout for exceptions related to JSch by sending some commands like `ls` or so

Comment: One comment on the suggestion from @Arvind  -- I suggest avoid using `ls` as that requires file system access, and there are things that can make that slow (parallel file systems, large directories). I'd suggest `id -u` or something similar. Nonetheless, the basic send something down the pipe is correct.

Comment: Won't a session.sendKeepAliveMsg be sufficient?

I can do R&D and finalize the code, but looking for any tried & tested approach i.e. running successfully for some time.

Comment: Just tried, session.sendKeepAliveMsg does not set isConnected to false.